# How to get a symmetrical TwoWay binding?

Tags: wpf, xaml

While debugging a problem in a WPF application, I have noticed that the `TwoWay` data binding does not seem to be symmetrical. Here is an example:

```
<Window x:Class="ConverterTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ConverterTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:TextConverter x:Key="textConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt1" Height="24" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt2" Height="24" Margin="0,40,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Text="{Binding ElementName=txt1, Path=Text, 
                        Mode=TwoWay,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                        Converter={StaticResource textConverter}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The converter looks like this:

```cs
public class TextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType,
         object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString().ToUpper();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, 
         object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString().ToLower();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

When editing inside `txt1`, only `Convert()` is called; but when editing inside `txt2`, first `ConvertBack()` and then `Convert()` is called.

In other words, `TwoWay` binding seems to work like this:

- When the source property is updated, the target property is updated.
- When the target property is updated, first the source property is updated, and then the target property is updated again.

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode.aspx) merely says:

> Causes changes to either the source property or the target property to automatically update the other.

From that sentence, I would have expected the following behavior:

- When the source property is updated, the target property is updated.
- When the target property is updated, the source property is updated.

Is there any way to achieve this symmetrical behavior (purely in XAML, without C# programming)?

**EDIT**: I just have discovered that in WPF 3.5, `TwoWay` bindings work symmetrical. In WPF 4.0, however, the behavior has changed (as described above).

Comment: That behavior in my mind is consistent with the documentation.  txt2 is a source of itself - think of the implications if it was not. If you want txt2 to not be a source then bind it oneway and use a textblock.

Comment: @Blam: I think there are good reasons for both a non-symmetrical and a symmetrical TwoWay binding. In my example above, if you type lower-case letters into txt2, they are unexpectedly converted into upper-case letters inside txt2 while you are typing. In that particular example it is not a big deal, but there may be other, more complex bindings (e.g. date/time formatting), where users certainly would be annoyed when WPF reformats the typed text. This could be easily avoided by a symmetrical TwoWay binding.

Comment: @Blam - It is easily avoided/doable/solved by dropping the 'no C#' requirement.

Comment: @fmunkert OK it does not make sense to u.  4 me it makes sense that an element be a source to itself and applies the attached converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, *entirely* symmetrical cannot be achieved because:

- When the source is updated, the control just has to show the new value, period. Nothing fancy happens.
- When the target is updated, before it is written to the source, the change of value can be canceled at a ridiculous amount of places.

For example: validation.

When the source is updated, say, from code, it passed all validation (unless you forgot to check, but that's another problem). The control just displays the new value.

When the target is updated, the value is first converted back in the converter to be manipulable, then coerced, validated and then at last, the source is set.

But as you see, the value could have been modified between the target and the source, so the value is converted again, and finally displayed.

Bonus: to understand where and in which order the value can change, see [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx).

Comment: You write: "the value could have been modified between the target and the source" That is exactly why I think there should be the option to have a symmetrical binding, such that conversions, coercions, and validations are not reflected back to the target. Admittedly, in most times the current WPF behavior seems to be OK, but there are cases where it is not (see my example above and my comment to Blam).

Comment: But if the values are not reflected on the target, then your source has a different value than the target. It defeats the purpose of binding!

Comment: If you don't want the letter to be converted to upper case while the user types in, just remove `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, it will default back to `LostFocus` and the conversion will happen when the focus moves away.

Comment: Microsoft Support reported that the WPF 4 behavior is by design, where as the WPF 3.5 behavior was considered to be buggy ( https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/733286/in-wpf-4-twoway-bindings-no-longer-are-symmetrical ). I do not agree, but I suppose I just have to live with it and add C# code to compensate for the change of behavior in WPF 4.